# May I add a custom attribute in SPField SchemaXML to create

Tags: rest, api, custom-field-types, spfield

Could I add a custom **attribute** *(MyCustomAttribute="true")* in SchemaXML of SP.Field and create it by REST API?

```
<Field Type="Text" DisplayName="AwesomeField" MaxLength="255" ID="{ff9e8535-6bdb-4ab3-8d1b-212098d51f84}" SourceID="{f6064664-17fd-4c38-b71e-b6d3b66fec00}" StaticName="AwesomeField" Name="AwesomeField" MyCustomAttribute="true" />
```

I need some property in a field to know the field was created by me (actually my application) or not.

Comment: Check [this](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/schema/field-element-field-types) & [this](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/schema/field-element-field) if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Adding custom attributes is not supported there, since the schema is strictly defined.

What you could do instead is to use the `Group` attribute and write the name of your application there. That way you can also filter all of your fields on the standard `site columns` web page (/_layouts/15/mngfield.aspx).

You can find more on the Field schema [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/schema/field-element-field).